# По улику нажать клавишу f11 с помощью js

Tags: javascript

`keyCode` клавиши `f11` = 122

если этот код запускает функцию по нажатию (!)клавиши на клавиатуре (вырезан из другого моего файла, сейчас появилась необходимость сделать наоборот):

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(c){
    //esc
    if((popup.classList == 'modal-image is-fade') && (c.keyCode == 27)){
        closeModal.click();
    }

    //right
    if((popup.classList == 'modal-image is-fade') && (c.keyCode == 39)){
        next.click();
    }

    //left
    if((popup.classList == 'modal-image is-fade') && (c.keyCode == 37)){
        prev.click();
    }
});
```

То, как написать функцию, которая будет имитировать клик по кнопке `f11(122)`?
Нажал на блок, открылся полноэкранный режим, т.е нажалась кнопка `f11`

Comment: это не так работает, для полноэкранного режима отдельное api: [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

Comment: @Grundy а что в мобильной версии будет? Тоже полноэкранный режим?

Comment: Попробуй :-))))